# Bind to a Service if exists

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service, android-activity

I'm working on a project that needs an activity to connect to a local service if that service is running and start it if it is not running.
What is the suitable flag for such approach.

Comment: Lol, the edits on this question completely reversed its meaning. GJ guys.

Comment: at the beginning there was `...and not create it if it is not`, now is `...and start it if it is not running`. answer address original one, for edited question proper answer would be to use `BIND_AUTO_CREATE` flag

Comment: @snachmsm / Jens I have to say yes the edit was wrong.. I remember why I asked that question, I wanted to connect to a services but not start it. but I haven't done android dev since years so I'm not really sure if the accepted answer is valid for the current question or the original one (what I intended)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is simply accomplished by, for instance, passing `0` in the last parameter to `#bindService(Intent, ServiceConnection, int)`.

E.g.

```
bindService(new Intent(this, MrMeService.class), new ServiceConnection(){
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
            System.out.println("Service disconnected");
        }
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
            System.out.println("Service connected");
        }
    }, 0);
```

The `#bindService(..)` call will return `true` but the service will **not** actually start and your service connection will not trigger *until* someone actually starts the service, e.g. using `#startService(Intent)`. At least this is how it works on ICS and Gingerbread.

Comment: This is a great answer since many others only suggest storing the boolean value returned by the bindService() method, and that's not true. THIS is right. NOTE: unbindService() does NOT call onServiceDisconnected() even though it unbinds from the service. 

Recommended:
onResume() -> bind(), onPause() -> unbind(), onEventToStart() -> start(), onEventToStop() -> stop().

Working in all devices I've tested it on.

Comment: @HvSimon It's been a while but I most likely meant it as your own event that triggered start and stopping the service. Whatever requires a background process.